# Install driver without plugging in device

Tags: installation, driver, device, inf

I'm trying to install some unsigned legacy drivers to my computer from command line.  I have used dpinst.exe and installhinfsection functions which work fine, however everything I've tried is software first, meaning it installs the driver onto your computer and then doesn't actually show up in the device manager until you plug the device into your computer.

I'm wanting to install the driver and have it show up in the device manager **without** having to plug in any devices.

I can do this with adding legacy hardware from the device manager, but I want this to be an automated process so all from command line and not having to do it manually through device manager.

thanks in advance

EDIT
The drivers were written by me (UserModeDriverFramework), they are emulating real devices.